# Filtering a sharepoint list in infopath without Code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I am creating a  browser enabled form and I would like to filter the results from a sharepoint list based on user input. if the user searches for the business unit "A" I would like a list of all locations that have a business unit of "A".

I have achieved this using code but the chaps that do the deployment want the from done without form code. can this be done and if so how?

I am using sharepoint 2007 and infopath 2007

my only real thought would be to create a web service that queries the SP list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked to of solved the issue now.

I added a repeating section with controls on the form based on the data connection to the SP list. I then added conditional formatting on the repeating section to hide the control where business from data source does not equal search key word on the form.